# iOS Custom Url Scheme in App does not open the first time Url scheme is used

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari

In my app I have configured a custom URL scheme "TestScheme". Everything works fine, but there is one problem.

When I open e.g. "TestScheme://xyz" in Safari, sometimes a dialog is opened in which I am asked whether I want to open the site in my app. When I tap on open nothing happens. When I open the same site in safari again, the app is opened correctly without showing the dialog.

Can anybody explain this strange behavior? Why doesn´t the app open when I tap open in the dialog?

I dont get this problem when redirecting to the custom URL scheme with href in HTML. The problem still exists when just typing in the URL in the browser though.

Comment: Is this behavior happening for built-in iOS apps? Or just your app?

Comment: I'm also facing a problem like this. In my case I'm trying to open my app with a custome urlscheme sometimes it woks perfectly. sometimes it only shows the message and nothing happens. Still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in development, it sounds like every time you compile and re-deploy the app the device, it takes time to register with the system.  Also, after a deploy you might want to make sure you kill Safari so it can load the custom Url schemes.

Just my two-cent.

Comment: I dont think that this is the actual problem, because the dialog also appers when just changing the content after the url scheme and not only when entering the custom url scheme the first time.

Comment: did you make the necessary modifications to info.plist in your app? URL Types/ URL Identifiers / URL Schemes...

What happens when you click cancel?! I'm having a problem where I click cancel on that dialog and then i need to refresh the page in order to be able to be prompted again with the same dialog.

Comment: We are having the same problem. Te recreate we just force close the app and try the link. The handler in openURL never gets called. The link just starts the app as if nothing was passed in. If the app is open, or has been opened recently, it gets handled fine and does what it's supposed to. i have this happening on Android as well... Maybe its a thing now... Still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the app has never been run since rebooted, is force closed, or killed by the OS watchdog at some point the only way we have got this to work is to ALSO handle and check for launch options in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` call. I have yet to stumble upon an `openURL` tutorial that reminds me of this...

You can see the url in the launch options when you put a little alert box to peek at what your getting under the hood at launch since I have yet to figure out how (or taken the the time to figure out how) to hook a debugger up and launch the app with a link. BTW I am using iOS 7.1.2 to test this right now.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Launch With Options"
                                                message:[launchOptions description]
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Then you can see what is sent and decide to take action/parse it there.

[Ironically I have the same **exact** launch behavior problem on Android to solve as well... I guess I need to parse the bundle in onCreate...]